# Losslessly convert from RGBA rawvideo to H.264

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am creating a tool that generates frames of RGBA video and pipes it to ffmpeg to create an .mp4 video. Here is the command that I give ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -y -f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -s 960x540 -pix_fmt rgba -r 60 -i - 
-an -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -b:v 995328k vigeo_demo.mp4
```

However, the quality is very, very, poor. The video consists of around 2-px wide lines being drawn across the screen at various angles. The lines are very blurry and blocky. What could be the cause of this and how do I fix it?

Things I've tried:

- `-q:v 0`
- `crf 1` (`crf 0` gives me an error)

Comment: If CRF 0 doesn't run for you, share full log of that command.

Answer (score 2):

You are downsampling the chroma, so thin lines will lose definition. Either use full chroma sampling

```
ffmpeg -y -f rawvideo -s 960x540 -pix_fmt rgba -framerate 60 -i - 
       -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv444p -crf 0 video_demo.mp4
```

or keep pixels as RGB.

```
ffmpeg -y -f rawvideo -s 960x540 -pix_fmt rgba -framerate 60 -i - 
       -c:v libx264rgb -crf 0 video_demo.mp4
```